# RabbitMQ exchange and queue

Tags: python, rabbitmq

I want to create a small multiplayer game with RabbitMQ. A single server can have multiple sessions at once. My question is how can i differentiate between the message queues. I have 2 basic message types: async for updates(sent to everyone within a session) and synchronous(for player interaction with game. Its players turn to do something etc.).

For async i use publish-subscribe pattern. Server is publisher and all players in session are subscribers. For that i use fanout.

For sync i use RPC pattern, each client has 2 queues for each function, 1 for sending and one for receiving.

My question is how can i set up the MQ-s in such a way that game sessions would not interfere with each other. My idea is this layered system: 1 layer is servers(server list), 2 layer is room list, and 3 layer is room. What would be a good way to set up this kind of thing.

I used https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html to set up my server currently. And it is working but now i want to extend it to multiple simultaneous sessions.

```
 def initChannels(self):
        self.updateConnection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
        self.updateChannel = self.updateConnection.channel()
        self.updateChannel.exchange_declare(exchange='updates',type='fanout')

        self.place = threading.Thread(target=self.placeListener,args=(self.place,))
        self.bomb = threading.Thread(target=self.bombListener, args=(self.bomb,))

        self.place.start()
        self.bomb.start()

def placeListener(self, place):
    self.placeConnection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
    self.placeChannel = self.placeConnection.channel()
    self.placeChannel.queue_declare(queue='rpc_place')

    self.placeChannel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
    self.placeChannel.basic_consume(place, queue='rpc_place')
    self.placeChannel.start_consuming()
```

This is the example on how i have setup my MQ-s. Its mostly like on the tuorial link.